# AWS Lambda@edge. Access browser cookie in origin response triggered function

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-s3, header, aws-lambda

(My setup: CloudFront + S3 Origin)

Hi everyone!

This is what I’m trying to do:

Step 1. Trigger a Lambda function on viewer request. Get cookie with user preferred language if available (this cookie is set when the user chooses site language).

Step 2. Trigger a Lambda function on origin response. If response is an error (ex. 404), return an error page to the viewer based on the preferred language cookie from step 1.

My question is: how do I make information gotten in step 1 available in step 2? In general, how do I process a response based on user request AND origin response information? I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Is the language cookie included in the whitelist of cookies that are forwarded to the origin (in the cache behavior settings)?  This will make a significant difference in how the solution will need to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need step 1.

Whitelist the cookie for forwarding to the origin in the cache behavior.  This causes CloudFront to cache a separate copy of each page, based on the value of the cookie.  You'd need this anyway if your origin is going to be able to see the cookie.

In Lambda@Edge, there are viewer-side triggers (in front of the cache) and origin-side triggers (behind the cache).

An Origin Response trigger can see the response returned from the origin, but can also see the request that was sent to the origin.

> **request**
>
> Origin response – The request that CloudFront forwarded to the origin and that might have been modified by the Lambda function that was triggered by an origin request event
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-response

There's not a straigtforward way to send information from a viewer request trigger to an origin response trigger, because they are on opposite sides of the cache and not able to communicate directly.

Your handler will be passed an `event`.

Everything you need is in `event.Records[0].cf`.

```
const cf = event.Records[0].cf;
```

The response is in `cf.response` and the request is in `cf.request`.

If the response status isn't 404, bail out of the origin response trigger and allow CloudFront to continue processing.

```
if(cf.response.status != "404')
{
  return callback(null, cf.response);
}
```

Otherwise, extract the cookie from `cf.request.headers.cookie` (you'll need to parse this array after verifying that it exists -- it will not, if the browser didn't supply cookies), generate your custom response based on the cookie, and return it.

See [Generated Responses - Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-generated-response-examples) for how to return a generated response.

Since you are generating the response in an origin response trigger, it will be stored in the cache according to the value of the [Error Caching Minimum TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html) (default 5 minutes).